# How to upgrade VB6 Design components?

Tags: dll, reference, user-controls, vb6

So I had this legacy project fall into my lap here recently. This application crashes at random intervals, and appears to have memory leak. First off, I am not a VB6 developer. I know virtually nothing about the language, or the IDE. Both of which I find pretty insufferable :(. Nevertheless, I have to attempt to make a fix for this software. The problem is related to the assembly MSVBVM60.DLL. After digging around I found this [bug](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=295330). The developer who had used this project before had used some user controls form a package called SimpleChart. I found the website once, but it was only a single page indicating they no longer actively develop, or even sell licenses to the components anymore. No documentation on its use, there or anywhere for that matter. I had profiled the application using Glowcode to detect a potential memory leak a college had thought might be buried in the application. Not knowing pretty much anything about anything I was looking at in Glowcode, I managed to have it run a conservative evaluation of the code at runtime to find leaks. This, oddly enough pointed me to that SimpleChart DLL, and further up the call stack was the MSVBVM60 DLL. I had found that we had stored several installers of the SimpleChart components locally, and found that I was several versions behind the latest version. I quickly grabbed the installer, and installed it onto my VB6 dev machine. From there I attempted to replace the referenced assembly with the upgraded one via the Project -> reference and Project -> components menus. Both of them result in the error:

Can't remove control or reference; in use.

So from what I gather from this error, and the sparse posts I found related to it, the control is being referenced by a form some place and needs to be removed before I can upgrade. The question then is, is it even possible to upgrade a version of a control in VB6 without having to rebuild all of the logic and everything associated with said control? I can delete the controls (well, I could if I had any idea which controls on the form were from SimpleChart), but wouldn't that mean I would have to rebuild all of the event handlers and everything for said component? It just seems to me that there must be a way to upgrade a component without undoing every ounce of work you had put into it.

I had tried simply modifying the vbp project to remove the reference, on some line that read Object=, followed by some junk, then a path to a DLL. This removed the reference but broke the form. From there, I added the reference to the new assembly, saved, and restarted my IDE hoping the control would fix itself with the replacement assembly being referenced. No such luck.

If anyone can help me, please try to be as verbose as possible. My background is java and .NET development. Mostly java. I understand quite a bit about programming, but virtually nothing about VB6.

An example of the EventViewer message:

```
Faulting application name: PTL Stats.exe, version: 2.4.0.2, time stamp: 0x537baff2
Faulting module name: MSVBVM60.DLL, version: 6.0.98.15, time stamp: 0x4a5bda6c
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0004c8b1
Faulting process id: 0x620
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfb540858788c7
Faulting application path: C:\ptl\Stats\PTL Stats.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\system32\MSVBVM60.DLL
Report Id: 96228ed9-224f-11e4-9c03-386077d55741
```

Comment: OCX controls are COM components so (if they've been written correctly) just installing and registering the latest version should do it. It's a lot more work to completely break compatibility to the point that it doesn't update automatically.
Also, once you've "broken the form" (missing control references) and saved it over the top, you'll need to restore an older version.

Comment: @Deanna So if I understand you correctly, I should be able to remove the reference from the vbp, open the project and add the reference to the newer version, save, revert the forms that were affected but leave the changes to the vbp, then reload and have it work? Or simply just running the new installer on the target machine?

Comment: Not quite. If you need to remove and readd the reference to the project then the forms will need to be reworked. My point was that normally you wouldn't need to do any of it. Upgrading a control is simply a matter of installing and registering it unless they've made radical changes. Have you tried reverting everything to known "good" and just seeing what happens with the new control?

Comment: I don't understand. If I install the new control, wont I just have say... SimpleChart_2.0.DLL and SimpleChart.2.2.DLL registered on the machine, and the application still target 2.0? - In the mean time, I will try simply installing the new component

Comment: It depends on the control. If they kept the same COM IDs then it will be upgraded. If they broke compatibility to allow side by side usage, then you will need to delete all existing references and recreate them (maybe reverting the code), as it is a "different" control. An easy way to tell is to try adding them both to the same project.

Comment: I can add them both at the same time. They refer to distinct entries in both the component and references list. Even the vbp file references SimpleChart3.DLL vs SimpleChart5.DLL. I tried just removing the older versions of the control from the machine, and installing just the lastest version. The app displays its splash screen then hangs indefinitely :(.... This is going to be painful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59591/discussion-between-deanna-and-mark-w).

Comment: The MSVBVM60.dll access violation you linked to was due to a flaw in the crusty old Msinet.ocx we have good alternatives to.  I doubt it has any bearing on your problem at all.  In any case it was fixed in VB6 SP6 (as the MS KB article linked to says quite explicitly).

Comment: @Bob77 That may be, and I am working on mostly speculation here, but event viewer points to that assembly as the faulting module, with the same error code as the one listed in that bug report. This is a 3rd party control, which uses that MS assembly, and it crashes randomly. That was about the only meaningful topic I could find for that error code on that assembly. Glowcode also pointed me to that MS DLL from the call stack on the SimpleChart object. I added the event viewer message to the OP. IMHO, its probably the SimpleChart controls causing the issue, but I still have to upgrade to test.

Comment: `msvbvm60.dll` contains the vast majority of the VB6 runtime. Almost every crash will show that in the call stack, and a fair number of unhandled exceptions will also be in that module due to the way VB6 works. 0xc0000005 is a general "Access violation" and can have any number of causes. Chances of an "Access violation in `msvbvm60.dll`" being the same as any other "Access violation in `msvbvm60.dll`" is very slim, especially in different programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the update is a minor update (same COM IDs) then the upgrade should be seamless as guaranteed by the COM system.

If it's a major update that includes a new type library/COM interfaces, then it will require some manual patching as there is no native "replace this control" command.

The main steps involve:

1. Add the new control to the project
2. Note the properties of the old controls and delete them from the form
3. Add the new control with the same name and reapply any custom properties
   All code will be left untouched by this so will still refer the new control
4. Repeat 2 and 3 for each instance
5. Remove the control from the project
6. Fix up any compile errors and changed events that will inevitably occur with an interface change
7. Test
8. Repeat 7

Alternatively, as the form files are textual, you can do steps 2 and 3 once, and see what the new control's progid is, replacing this manually in each other occurrence.

If you have source control or a backup of the original code, it will make reapplying any custom properties easier.

Comment: Ultimately, there was nothing I could do anyway. The controls from SimpleChart ended up crashing the IDE when we try to add them to a form. I attempted to upgrade the components by referencing both components, and rebuilding the new one along side the old one in design view, but whatever machine I tried on, with whatever version (including the existing component), as soon as the component name dialog closed with a valid name, the IDE would crash to desktop. In all likelihood we will end up replacing the entire component with something else.